# Having trouble linking libcurl in code::blocks

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have installed cURL on my windows computer successfully. I can run cURL commands in console successfully. However, in windows I am getting a bunch "undefined reference" errors when I run this code:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    const char* szURL = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/TheCarpStandsUp?api_key=RGAPI-40d6fff4-cc4c-467b-8c06-96ac90878ae4";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, szURL);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following errors

```html
||=== Build: Debug in LeagueAssistant (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|17|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|21|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|25|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|28|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_cleanup'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 8 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have added the libcurl.a file to my build options linker settings, and I added the include directory to the search directories.

Comment: "When it runs I get the following errors" No, those are not runtime errors. Those are _linker_ errors. You need to resolve those before your program can run.

Comment: Probably, you need to add a path to the curl *library* in the *linker* options.

Comment: I've already done that, assuming that is the .a file

Comment: See the [curl FAQ](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Link_errors_when_building_libcur).

Comment: So I got the linking working, but I don't have a dll file for some reason